# Strange rendering of LaTeX

Tags: bug, mathjax

I am on Windows XP running Chrome and IE 7. Both of them render this type of $\LaTeX$. Is there anything that I can do to fix it?

> Chrome version : Version 22.0.1229.79 m
>
> XP Professional; Version 2002; Service Pack 3
>
> IE 7 Version 7.0.5730.13

[image]

[image]

The problem is that equations in-line do not show, but paragraph equations show just fine.

Comment: Works fine for me on XP with IE8 and Chrome 5.

Comment: @Bill I don't think it is a problem that everyone faces. I think it is only certain people (i.e. myself).

Comment: What version of Chrome and XP are you running? Does the problem persist after reloading the page? After clearing the browser cache? Does the problem with in-line equations occur only after a displaystyle ("paragraph") equation? (e.g. look at post with no displaystyle equations)

Comment: @pica just to clarify: is this on all questions or just this one.

Comment: @Bill what it is worth, in the image there are some inline math in the title of the post which appears "before" the body text in the HTML source.

Comment: @willie, it is on all questions, though there is a difference sometimes.

Comment: Oh, your second image shows something interesting! The parts that are displayed are _not_ in a displayed math (double `$` enclosed) environment. They are actually **inline**! The difference is that there is a `\begin ... \end` environment pair for the matrix. So the difference may be more subtle than just inline versus displayed mathematics.

Comment: Do you have any extensions installed in Chrome.  In particular, any that might be loading their own copy of MathJax?  It looks like the configuration doesn't include dollar signs as in-line math delimiters.  That is the default for MathJax (math.SE enables them explicitly), so it looks like something may be changing the configuration for you.  @WillieWong, MathJax looks for `\begin...\end` and turns them into display math, so if the in-line delimiters don't include dollars, MathJax will find those tags within them and make them displays.

Comment: Can you try typing `javascript:alert(MathJax.Extension.tex2jax.config.inlineMath)` in the URL typein at the top of the browser and let us know what it reports.  If it doesn't include dollar signs, then that is the problem.

Comment: nothing happens on Chrome: It redirects to https://www.google.com/search?q=alert(MathJax.Extension.tex2jax.config.inlineMath)&oq=alert(MathJax.Extension.tex2jax.config.inlineMath)&sugexp=chrome,mod=7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Make sure you do it from the page where you are seeing the error, and make sure the `javascript:` gets pasted in.  I just tried it and it seems that Chrome removes the `javascript:` (probably for security reasons), so you may have to type that yourself.

Comment: @Davide, you are correct, it does not show dollar signs.

Comment: So do you have any extensions installed that might be affecting the MathJax configuration?  The dollar sign configuration is included explicitly in the page, so I don't see how that could not be getting to MathJax unless you had something else overriding it.

Comment: @Davide, No, nothing is installed. This behavior is observed on both Chrome and IE

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the problem.  Both IE7 and Chrome 22 work fine for me in Windows XP.  So I'm thinking there must be something unusual about your setup.  Let's take this off line for now until we figure it out; please contact me via email: dpvc at union dot edu.

Answer (score 3):

I do not know if this is the best solution.. but I "force fixed" it on chrome with [math anywhere](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/math-anywhere/gebhifiddmaaeecbaiemfpejghjdjmhc?hl=en-US)